# ng-multiselect-dropdown adding a "alt" tag to checkbox label element

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown, multi-select

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown in my application to render a list of checkboxs. Now the requirement is to show a icon beside each of the label with a information icon and on hover of that icon i have to show a short description. is there a method to achieve that as in this image ?

Please find the below code which i am using.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HWek.png to be achieved

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'6xx'" [data]="this.thirdtDropDown" 
[settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"></ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: do you mean add icon to each of the option and hover to show tooltip?

Comment: yes, i want to add icon and show tooltip